# Odds ratios from a logistic regression, can they be converted to r?

Tags: logistic, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I am conducting a meta-analysis of risk factors for PTSD. I am extracting r for each risk factor, or if correlations have not been used in the paper I am calculating r from the data given.

In one of the papers the authors have presented mean scores and standard deviations for the ptsd group and non ptsd group on continuous variables that I am considering 'risk factors.' They have also given the number of people in a certain categories (e.g. male/female) with and without ptsd, which I am also considering 'risk factors.' In the paper, all of these variables (continuous and categorical) have been entered into a logistic regression and the odds ratios have been presented.

Should I calculate r by converting the odds ratios from the logistic regression to r for all variables? Or is it more sensitive if I calculate r from the means and standards deviations for the continuous variables and from the numbers in each group for the categorical variables? When I have done it both the ways the results are different.

Comment: What does "r" stand for??

Comment: Pearson correlation coefficient, used as an effect size for this meta-analysis

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1d95/1c8c87e41d4e0821cb075d7f8cab237bc6c3.pdf